# How to limit bandwidth use for watching videos?

Tags: networking

I currently run into this issue that when 2-3 videos are watched concurrently my site becomes unresponsive due to the outgoing traffic being  too high.

How can I limit the bandwidth usage for watching video and listening to audio so that bandwidth usage never exceeds the server's limits?

Comment: You want to limit the amount of bandwidth your website uses per client?

Comment: I would like to limit the total bandwidth that can be used for watching video/audio for example.

Comment: Typically you would just serve content that requires less bandwidth.  We are talking about, your website serving content to visitors, and you want to limit the amount of bandwidth each visitor uses, right?

Comment: The issue I ran into is that larger video files are stored on the server and when two, three are watched at the same time by different users the outgoing traffic is too much for my server to handle. As you can see here http://i.imgur.com/auNw5OP.png

Comment: Your question is out of scope, this problem is more of how to handle content delivery, then limiting a specific client.  But if your only having this problem with 3 clients you simply need more bandwidth

Comment: I think his question is fine. He wants a solution to work with the limited resources he has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually your webserver is responsible for streaming videos via the HTTP protocol. I assume you're using `nginx`:

```
location ^~ /videos/ {
...
limit_rate_after 1m;
limit_rate 100k;
...
}
```

this would limit the rate to 1mbit per stream. Each user could still open an unlimited amount of streams. To limit the amount of streams per user you'd need to create a zone.

[How to Limit Nginx download Speed](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/how-to-limit-nginx-download-speed/)